# How to add multiple lines of the Formset?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms

i work on the form for users.
They have to add many model objects in the appropriate form.
one line is displayed when entering the GET method,
they will type in input name = "add-rows-number" the number should be displayed the number of forms in the formset

I tried with formset and with model formsetfactory

```
class AddCostCenters(View):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AddCostCenters, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.FormSet = modelformset_factory(CostCenter, form=CostCenterAddForm, extra=self.get_form_size)


    def get_form_size(self, request):
        extra_rows_num = 1
        if 'add-rows' in request.POST:
                extra_rows_num += int(request.POST.get('add-rows-number'))
        return extra_rows_num

    def get(self, request, proceeding_id):
        costcenter_model = CostCenter.objects.filter(
            participation__provider__user=request.user,
            participation__proceeding=proceeding_id
        )

        return TemplateResponse(request, 'costcenteradd.html', context)

    def post(self, request, proceeding_id):
        costcenter_model = CostCenter.objects.filter(
            participation__provider__user=request.user,
            participation__proceeding=proceeding_id
        )

        # if 'add-rows' in request.POST:
        #     try:
        #         rows_to_show = int(request.POST.get('add-rows-number'))
        #     except ValueError:
        #         rows_to_show = 0
        #     self.extra_rows_number += rows_to_show


        if 'save_form' in request.POST:
            new_cost_centers = []
            post_formset_data = self.FormSet(request.POST)

            if post_formset_data.is_valid():
                instances = post_formset_data.save(commit=False)
                new_cost_centers.append(instance)
                        # do something

            else:
                post_form = post_formset_data


        context = {
            'form': post_form,
        }
        return render(request, 'costcenteradd.html', context)
```

## form

```
 class CostCenterAddForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # helper = CostCenterAddFormSetHelper()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CostCenterAddForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_show_labels = False

        for field_name, field in self.fields.items():
            field.help_text = None

    class Meta:
        model = CostCenter
        fields = (
            'id',
            'cost_center_account_no',
            'cost_center_account_name',
            'departmental_code',
            'values_for_year',
            'only_total_cost_of_cost_center',
        )
        exclude = (
            'participation',
            'to_check',
            'is_checked',
            'accepted',
            'use_in_calculations',
        )
```

## html

```
<div class="container-fluid ">
      <form method="post">
          {% csrf_token %}
          {{ form.management_form }}
                <div class="row sticky-top text-center form-nav">
                    <div class="col-md-2 content_center"> Numer Konta OPK </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 content_center"> Nazwa konta OPK </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 content_center"> Kod resortowy  </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1 content_center"> Rok za który jest postępowanie </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1 content_center"> Uproszczone dane finansowe </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 content_center"> Usuń </div>
                </div>
                <div class="section sticky-top my-2 form-panel ">
                    <div class="row sticky-top my-2">
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <button class="btn btn-success btn-block" type="submit" name="save_form">Zapisz</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                <input class="form-control" min="1" type="number" name="add-rows-number"
                                value={{form.total_form_count }}
                                placeholder="number" aria-label="add form rows ">
                                <div class="input-group-append">
                                    <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit" name="add-rows">show_rows</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
      <hr>
            {% for field in form %}
            <div class="row text-center">
                <div class="col-md-2 paste-in">
                {{field.cost_center_account_no | as_crispy_field}}
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 paste-in">
                {{field.cost_center_account_name | as_crispy_field}}
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 paste-in">
                {{field.departmental_code | as_crispy_field}}
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1 paste-in">
                {{field.values_for_year | as_crispy_field}}
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1">
                {{field.only_total_cost_of_cost_center | as_crispy_field}}
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                <input type="submit" name="del_btn{{ field.instance.id }}" value="del"
                       {% if field.instance.id == None %}
                        class="btn btn-outline-secondary" disabled
                       {% else %}
                        class="btn btn-outline-danger"
                       {% endif%} />
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: that's a lot of code. But more important, what's your problem? you're not saying what you see, if you have an error, what's happening. You're not asking a question, basically.

Comment: Problem is that i can't multiply forms in view. i try to change extra vale from model form field but in request post is forms-TOTAL_FORMS vale witch overwrite my value. 
1. I need to show one form on get if model dosn't have objects else show all obj
2. if if needed add more forms by passing vale in input.
3. paste vales and create del or update obj

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the `formset` in both your `get()` and `post()` methods and add it to your context. You use the `queryset` attribute to populate it with existing instances:

```
formset = self.FormSet(queryset=CostCenter.objects.filter(...))
# or
formset = self.FormSet(queryset=CostCenter.objects.filter(...), data=request.POST)
```

Then in your template, you loop through your `formset` (what you call `form` in your template is actually a formset):

```
{{ formset.management_form }}
{% for form in formset %}
    {{ form.cost_center_account_no|as_crispy_field }}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

In your definition of `self.FormSet`, set `extra=1` so users have at least one extra row. Remove the calculation, because that cannot work. `request` isn't available in the `__init__()` of a `View` (it gets added with `as_view()`).

Now I would not have users submit the number of extra rows, you can just deduct it from the input data. Write some javascript to let users add rows themselves directly, like you see in the admin:

- Add a + button to add an extra row
- The javascript clones the previous row, adds it to the list of forms (with empty input fields)
- The javascript also updates the value for TOTAL_FORMS and MAX_FORMS input fields (hidden fields in the management form)

This way when users submit the formset, it will have the extra rows.

Comment: Gresy by I need to add multiple forma for user because he can paste data for event 200 obj at once

Comment: I don’t understand. You cannot paste multiple fields at once in a HTML form. Are you saying you want them to paste values for 200 fields one by one? Then adding rows using javascript is not a problem. But No one in their right mind will want to do that. Build a csv file upload form and process the csv in one go.